# I want to make sure a couple field do not exist before adding them using a Variable

Tags: vba, variables, ms-access, field

I am stuck. I have a table with fields using the Company Name and Emp Nbr, Hire Date, and Job Code. Like ([Amazon Emp Nbr], [Amazon Hire Date], Amazon Job Code]). I started with known fields and I have got Len to work but when I try to use a variable I hit a wall. I use a query in the form's RecordSource that pulls all fields for the user logged in. I could step through all the fields but I know the field I want to look for. There has to be a better way.

So these work.

```
MsgBox (Len(Me.PID.Name))
MsgBox (Len(Me.[First Name].Name))
MsgBox (Len(Me.[Last Name].Name))
```

But I need to use a variable ... Let me try to explain.

```
strAnswer = MsgBox("Do You Want To Enter A New Company Name? ", vbYesNo, "Do You Want To Enter A New Company Name?")

    If strAnswer = "7" Then
        MsgBox ("You Clicked NO. Please Reenter!")  'Reenter What?
        GoTo EndSection
    End If

    If strAnswer = "6" Then
        MsgBox ("You Clicked YES. Please enter your Information!")  'Enter New User Information!
        'This starts the section to enter a new employee Information.
        strNewCompanyName = UCase(InputBox("Please Enter the New Company Name", "Enter the New Compay Name", "?"))

        If (strNewCompanyName = "") Then
        MsgBox ("You Pressed Cancel")
        Forms!StartUp.SetFocus
        DoCmd.Maximize
        GoTo EndSection
        End If

    If (strNewCompanyName = "?") Then
        MsgBox ("You Forgot To Enter A NEW Company Name")
        Forms!StartUp.SetFocus
        DoCmd.Maximize
    End If
End If

    VarTest = ([Amazon Emp Nbr].Value)    'This works! Returns Value!

    'These don't
    VarTest = "[" & strNewCompanyName & " Emp Nbr]" 
    VarTest = "Me![" & strNewCompanyName & " Emp Nbr]"
    VarTest = Eval("[" & strNewCompanyName & " Emp Nbr]")
    VarTest = Eval("[" & strNewCompanyName & " Emp Nbr]").Value
    VarTest = [ & strNewCompanyName & _Emp_Nbr]
    VarTest = "[" & strNewCompanyName & " Emp Nbr].Value"
```

I want to use Len but can't even get it to return the value in the Field.

Then add Field ... Like ...
         DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE [Employee Inventory Table] ADD COLUMN [Amazon Enterprises] TEXT (25);"

More like ...
        DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE [Employee Inventory Table] ADD COLUMN "[" & strNewCompanyName & " Emp Nbr]" TEXT (25);"

I hope this makes sense ...Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you use CallByName with vbGet?

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with CallByName. I will try to look it up.

Comment: Not sure if appropriate was a thought

Answer (score 0):

There is another syntax to refer to fields in the form, that does what you want. Try:

```
Me(variableName).Value
```

That should do it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anywhere in your post where you use that syntax. It should work, if I understand the problem correctly. Concatenation has no influence here, as you can in fact concatenate the right value in the variable and then use just it.